# Sliding the banner images horizontally

Tags: ios

I am using this code for loading banner images one by one.

```
 NSArray *imagesArray;
 int photoCount;
 UIImageView *imageView;

-(void)setupImageView{
     photoCount = 0;
     [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imgA.png"] ,
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"imgB.png"] ,
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"imgC.png"] ,
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"imgD.png"] ,
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"imgE.png"] , 
                                     nil];
     imageView =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];
     imageView.image = [imagesArray objectAtIndex:photoCount];
     [self.view addSubview:imageView];
     [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:20.0 target:self selector:@selector(transitionPhotos) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
 }

-(void)transitionPhotos{
    if (photoCount < [imagesArray count] - 1){
        photoCount ++;
    }else{
        photoCount = 0;
    }
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.imageView
                  duration:2.0
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^{ imageView.image = [imagesArray objectAtIndex:photoCount]; }
                completion:NULL];    
}
```

But I need to slide the images horizontally one after another in after some time interval. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT:

Make a new view controller named "ImageSliderViewController" and copy this code in ImageSliderViewController.m file and add the attached images in the project.

```
#import "ImageSliderViewController.h"

@interface ImageSliderViewController ()
{
    int intMaxLength,intStartPosition;
    UIScrollView *imageSlider;
    NSTimer *timerForImageSlider;
}
@end

@implementation ImageSliderViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    imageSlider = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 20, 270, 180)];
    [self.view addSubview:imageSlider];

    [imageSlider setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];
    [imageSlider setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [imageSlider setScrollEnabled:NO];

    NSArray *imagesArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"] ,
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"] ,
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"] ,
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"] ,
                            nil];

    [imageSlider setContentSize:CGSizeMake([imagesArray count]*270, 180)];

    intMaxLength = [imagesArray count] * 270;


    int xPosition = 0;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < [imagesArray count] ; i++)
    {
        UIImageView *ivImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPosition, 0, 270, 180)];

        ivImage.image = [imagesArray objectAtIndex:i];

        [imageSlider addSubview:ivImage];

        xPosition += 270;
    }

    intStartPosition = 0;

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer;

    recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
    [recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];
    [[self view] addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];

    recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
    [recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)];
    [[self view] addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];

    timerForImageSlider = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(imageSlider) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(IBAction)handleSwipeFrom:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
    if (sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)
    {
        if(intMaxLength <=intStartPosition+270 )
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            intStartPosition += 270;
            [imageSlider setContentOffset:CGPointMake(intStartPosition,0) animated:YES];
        }

    }
    else if(sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)
    {
        if(0 > intStartPosition-270 )
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            intStartPosition -= 270;
            [imageSlider setContentOffset:CGPointMake(intStartPosition,0) animated:YES];
        }

    }
}
-(void)imageSlider
{
    if(intMaxLength <=intStartPosition+270 )
    {
        [imageSlider setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,0) animated:YES];
        intStartPosition = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        intStartPosition += 270;
        [imageSlider setContentOffset:CGPointMake(intStartPosition,0) animated:YES];
    }

}
@end
```

Images are here::::

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: thankyou iBhavesh..this is second time you are helping me :) thankyou very much

Comment: u already helped me in this topic  "how to populate data into UItableView by fetching data from database in ios [on hold]"

Comment: i have a error in that at the point of "setContentOffset",.. what is svHotelImage?? is this a image or imageview

Comment: it is not sliding horizontally bro...it is loading images one after other

Comment: can you help me for horizontal sliding image

Comment: what is the size of your images?

Comment: bro have you seen the screen shot

Comment: 1st image is in first first screen shot...and second  image is slowly loading depending on timestamp

Comment: i placed images in your post

Comment: ivImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPosition, 0, 270, 180)];

Comment: this is what i have written 270 180

Comment: is it sliding horizontally bro?? have you checked it

Comment: it will not slide automatically bro??

Comment: how to make it slide automatically... without swiping

Comment: iam getting a white screen bro nothing is displayed in the simulator....wat are the contents we have to ad in .xib file

Comment: Have you added all the code and images with proper name?There is nothing in the xib file because UIScrollView is added dynamically....make the names of images to "1.png" , "2.png" and so on...and add images in to your project...

Comment: i have done as you said ..but yet i didnt get the output it just display a white screen bro

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//in [self viewDidLoad]
height = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
.
.
.
void)transitionPhotos{
        if (photoCount < [imagesArray count] - 1){
        photoCount ++;
        }else{
        photoCount = 0;
        }
        yourImageView.frame = CGRectMake(width, 0, 0, height);
        [UIView beginAnimations:Nil context:Nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        yourImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: No, it will look like the animation of controller presenting(similar to horizontal sliding) for sliding actual effect, make a full screen collection view with cell size of your screen and use a simple pageControll down on screen ... and enable paging of collectionView